# Two different monomorphisms of a ring R into the same ring S

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I would like to know the simplest example of two monomorphisms of unital rings from a ring $R$ into a ring $S$ so that I can have an example of different copies of the same ring $R$ inside the bigger ring $S$.

Answer (score 6):

Find two injections from $k[X]$ into $k[Y,Z]$.

Comment: In fact, given any element $u\in k[X,Y]$ which is not a constant polynomial there is an injection $f:k[X]\to k[X,Y]$ such that $f(X)=u$. And all of these have different images!

Answer (score 2):

Given two commutative rings $R, S$, the universal commutative ring admitting morphisms from both $R$ and $S$ is their [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_algebras) $R \otimes S$ (over $\mathbb{Z}$). Setting $R = S = \mathbb{Z}[x]$, the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}[x] \otimes \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x, y]$, and this gives two injections $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x, y], \mathbb{Z}[y] \to \mathbb{Z}[x, y]$. Mariano's example is a generalization of this example to $k$-algebras.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for the simplest example, I nominate $R=S=\mathbb Z[X]$ and the two monomorphisms obtained by sending $X\mapsto X$ (the identity map) and $X\mapsto -X$.

Comment: This does not give «two copies» of the domain ring, strictly :-)

Comment: I took "copy" to include the copying map, but one can get the images to be distinct by changing $-X$ to $2X$.  Unfortunately, that might only be tied for "simplest", depending on how one judges competitors like $-2X$ or $3X$.